Marriage of a non-muslin for a woman
As-salam 'alaykum,
I am a divorced 56 year old Muslim woman that was abused verbally and physically in my marriage. I am unable to have any more children and I am alone. I have been approached several times by non- Muslim men. If they are not Muslim am I allowed to marry them if they consider studying and converting?
